# Android Background Service disconnects after minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, pusher, background-service, pusher-js

I'm trying to build a `background service` for notifications to run and show notifications even if the app is not in memory

but the issue, after a period of time the broadcast service i'm using, disconnects after like 8 minutes and i'm not able to recieve notifications, like the service is dead.

I'm using **Pusher** for the notifications part. and i'm subscribing and listening to an event in the broadcast service.

I can see in the **Pusher** debug console, the device disconnects after period of time.

What is the best way to build a background service that keeps running even if app is closed or not in memory.

and of course it should be cross-version of android.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public class BackgroundUpdateService extends Service {

    /**
     * Author：Hardik Talaviya
     * Date：  2019.08.3 2:30 PM
     * Describe:
     */

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundLocation";
    private Context context;
    private boolean stopService = false;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;
    private NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Background Service onCreate :: ");
        super.onCreate();
        context = this;

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    //Add Here your code if you want start in background
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
                }
            }
        };
        if (!stopService) {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        Log.e(TAG, "onTaskRemoved :: ");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand :: ");
        StartForeground();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "BackgroundService onDestroy :: ");
        stopService = true;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
    }

    /*-------- For notification ----------*/
    private void StartForeground() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_location";
        String CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_location";

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setColorized(false);
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
            builder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
            builder.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_NONE);
        } else {
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID);
        }
        builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
        builder.setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText("Your Text");
        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        builder.setSound(notificationSound);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notification_app_icon);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        startForeground(101, builder.build());
    }
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining _why_ it helps. For example, "using a _foreground service_ makes your app less likely to be killed by the OS".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [background execution limit](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) issue.
Solution: You should use startForeground in your service.